# Can I run both the Old and New consoles in Windows 10 at the same time?

Tags: windows, console

Using Windows 10 (currently 1803) I have 'console' apps that will run only in the new console [1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) and similarly others requiring the old NT console.

The problem and question is I can't find how to run 2 console app of the opposite 'genders' at the same time ! In the Windows registry I set "ForceV2" =1 under "HKCU\Console", and then all non-GUI programs will (try to) run in the new console; now the problem arises whenever I must run a programme incompatible with the V2-console : I will launch such a programme from a desktop shortcut (for instance) where I select "use the new console' under the shortcut's "options" tab. This works eventually BUT it appears that it also RESETS the global (per-user) above mentionned "ForceV2" registry key. Conversely and unfortunately, when "ForceV2" equals zero, it appears ALL console programmes will use the old - V1 - style of console.

I'm probably & hopefully missing something : is it POSSIBLE to choose the style of the console used by individual console programmes, whether from shortcuts and/or launched in other ways (the "run" box, clicking on the executable in Explorer...) ?

Comment: Which registry entries have you changed and what were their effects? Please don't answer in a comment, but rather [edit](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit) your post.

Comment: I wonder, which app can't run in V2 console? Anyway, what is the problem with setting up registry key each time before you run the app?

Comment: @Maximus : The new Linux-on-Windows (WSL) subsystem won't run unless "ForceV2" is set in the already mentioned registry key. As for programmes that won't run or even start in the new console I won't name names (they exist). // But, You're right, it is possible to have programmes run side by side using the old and new console hosts. Just not immediately intuitive, and not convenient, but possible. Had I found out earlier, I wouldn't have posed this at Stackexchange. Thank you! and apologies to everybody.

Comment: Just a note. This may be easily implemented in ConEmu. I've filled an issue: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1864

Comment: Noted and appreciated, @Maximus ! Meanwhile, I've solved (or is it worked around?) the issue by configuring 2 shortcuts on desktop that invoke the c.l. registry editor (reg.exe) via simple batch (.cmd) files, thus e.g. the following command :  C:\WINDOWS\System32\reg.exe add HKCU\Console /v ForceV2 /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f    ... to restore the Old Console and conversely " DWORD /d 1 /f " to switch back to the New (V2) console. Would you, or should I, consider turning these here comments into a fleshed Reply ?

Comment: Please create an answer yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each time a console application is launched, Windows 10 looks up one place only to choose the style of console - old or new - namely the value named "*ForceV2*" under the user's registry key "*HKCU\Console*". Confusingly this settings can be accessed and changed from the "properties" of  a Windows console executable or a shortcut, but contrary to other exe and shortcut "properties", the "ForceV2" value is **not** stored in the shortcut-file nor in the programme-specific subkey, if any, of "HKCU\console" ! These UI affect the unique, global (per user) key only.

There does not seem to be a strong reason why this value receives this special treatment - I guess it might change in future builds. 
In fact, the good point is consoles both new and old-style **can** definitely run side by side ! As noted by *Maximus* in comments, one must simply toggle the global registry key to the desired, or required, value before launching a new console process.

Using the command line registry editor (reg.exe) - here preferred over Regedit whose use is fastidious and requires several confirmation "clicks", one would 
`C:\WINDOWS\System32\reg.exe add HKCU\Console /v ForceV2 /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`
     for enabling the new (V2) console, and conversely :
`C:\WINDOWS\System32\reg.exe add HKCU\Console /v ForceV2 /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f` 
    which reverts to the old (v1) console.

These commands can be entered as simple batch (.cmd) one-liners whose shortcuts can be placed on the Windows desktop, allowing User fast to switch the type of console before launching a programme - without affecting previously launched and running console app, if any.